# Como executar função JavaScript na página current através do Application Controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails4

Estou fazendo uma validação de browser (IE < 10) através do Application Controller com a [`gem "browser"`](https://github.com/fnando/browser). Preciso que de qualquer página da aplicação que seja acessada, seja executada uma função JavaScript com uma mensagem dizendo que o *browser* não é recomendado.

Alguma idéia, sugestão ou outro jeito de fazer isso de forma dinâmica?

Código:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :is_ie_browser?

  def is_ie_browser?
    if browser.ie? && browser.version.to_i < 10
      #executar uma funcao
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa de gem nem passar pelo Rails.

Coloque nos seus javascripts uma função que verifique e dê a mensagem.

Usando jquery é simples:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/

Comment: Blz @AlexTakitani, obrigado! Ja tinha passado por essa solução, mas queria algo mais automático, tenho vários layouts e uns tem arquivos js que outros não tem. Nesse caso teria que passar por todos e add o arquivo com a function. Também não estou a usar o application.js em alguns layouts

Comment: Jefferson, vc deveria usar o application em todos os layouts. Tirando você perde as vantagens do asset pipeline.

Comment: Concordo @AlexTakitani, mas em alguns layouts estava gerando alguns conflitos.